# Categorised data in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I am looking for a suggestion on how to categorised/group data in PowerBi.

For example,
I have set up a conditional column in Power Query to achieve the results seeing in “Group” column by saying if ID is 8304 then Group B, if ID is 8660 then Group F -- but the database is large and I am already facing a performance issue when trying to set up a report based on individual Groups, it takes long to load the data.

Is there any alternative or better approach to group data?

| ID | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 8015 | A |
| 8020 | A |
| 8229 | A |
| 8304 | B |
| 8389 | B |
| 8391 | C |
| 8414 | D |
| 8421 | A |
| 8469 | A |
| 8572 | A |
| 8619 | F |
| 8660 | F |
| 8663 | J |
| 9102 | A |
| 9104 | K |
| 9120 | A |

Answer (score 0):

> I have set up a conditional column in Power Query to achieve the results seeing in “Group” column by saying if ID is 8304 then Group B, if ID is 8660 then Group F

Instead of a conditional column, use a helper table to store these links.

You can add the information to your main table by joining the two tables.